# Setting rules 'max-classes-per-file' in my angular project. Error trigger by ESLint is '"File has too many classes"

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to set a global rule "max-classes-per-file" in `eslintrc.json` file to turn off ESLint error "File has too many classes".

Trying to define the rule directly in the file works fine, but I'm really trying to set it globally.

I might be defining that rules incorrectly because it does not impact my file.

My definition:

```
...
rules: {
'max-classes-per-file': 'off',
}
```

Comment: Maybe `'off'` should be `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa, I simply didn't pay attention. After closing the file and reopening it, the linting rule applied accordingly

Answer (score 0):

To configure in globally in your repository you need to add this  `"max-classes-per-file": "off",` line in your root level `.eslintrc.json`

Your rules in this file will look alike

```
"rules": {
  "no-shadow": "off",
  "no-param-reassign": "off",
  "eol-last": "off",
  "max-classes-per-file": "off",
  "import/extensions": [ 1, {
    "js": "always", "json": "always"
  }]
},
```

You can refer to the following documentation for further information
[Eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#disabling-rules)

Answer (score -1):

error in `"` instead of `'` and `false` instead of `off`

```
  "rules": {
    "max-classes-per-file": false    
  },
```

More info - [max-classes-per-file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/max-classes-per-file)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Edit your eslintrc.json file

Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error

"rules": {
"max-classes-per-file": 0,
},

Comment: `'off'` and `0` do the same thing, and the former is arguably more readable.